# Null Pointer Exception in Windowbuilder Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, windowbuilder

I keep receiving an error about NullPointerException for my code where I do anything with chckbxAdmin, im not sure why, could anyone help?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String newUserPassword = addPassword.getText();
    File passwords = new File("src/guiProject/passwordList");
    File adminPasswords = new File("src/guiProject/adminPasswordList");
    File adminList = new File("src/guiProject/adminList");
    File names = new File("src/guiProject/nameList");
    if (chckbxAdmin.isSelected() == true) {
        save(adminPasswords, newUserPassword);
        String fullName = addLastName.getText() + ", " + addFirstName.getText();
        save(adminList, fullName);
    }
    save(passwords, newUserPassword);
    String fullName = addLastName.getText() + ", " + addFirstName.getText();
    save(names, fullName);
    txtStatus.setText("User Added Successfully");
    addPassword.setText("");
    addFirstName.setText("");
    addLastName.setText("");
    chckbxAdmin.setSelected(false);
}
```

chckbxAdmin is initialized at the top of my code and defined later in this segment:

```
JCheckBox chckbxAdmin = new JCheckBox("User is an Admin");
chckbxAdmin.setSelected(false);
chckbxAdmin.setBounds(82, 210, 147, 23);
adminAddPasswordScreen.add(chckbxAdmin);
```

Comment: In what line is the exception being thrown? Can you share the stacktrace?

Comment: Its any line that references chckbxAdmin, so its first occurs in the "if" statement

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at guiProject.mainWindow$6.actionPerformed(mainWindow.java:258)
 at (long list of different built in functions)

Comment: That suggests that chckbxAdmin hasn't been initialised. Can you show us how you do initialise it? Are you certain that occurs before your method?

Comment: I have updated my question to show this

Comment: So then is 'JCheckBox chckbxAdmin' a local variable there? By any chance do you have it set as a global and local variable? If that is supposed to be a global variable then you want to initialise it as 'chckbxAdmin = new JCheckBox("User is an Admin");' otherwise you will only be declaring it in a local scope to that method

Comment: I have defined it the same way I have defined everything else in my code and this is the only thing giving me an issue, it has to be something with the .getSelected and .setSelected because thats causing the error.

Comment: That seems unlikely to be the cause, JCheckbox.isSelected() can't return null. Can you print 'System.out.println("Test: " + chckbxAdmin)' at the start of your actionPerformed method?

Comment: It outputted "Test: null"

Comment: Then your object has definitely not been set. Can you try changing your statement to just 'chckbxAdmin = new JCheckBox("User is an Admin")' and tell us the result?

Comment: So, that got rid of the error, im having a seperate issue now but I might be able to fix it, thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. That happen because when you create a variable in a method like that it always takes priority if a global variable also shares it's name. A nice way to know is that a lot of IDE's will highlight global variables a different colour